# Dynamodb - boto for python: Search items by date range

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with 3 attributes:

```
ID - String, unique
StartDate - String (ISO date format)
EndDate - String (ISO date format)
```

I'd like to get all ID's with StartDate >= x and EndDate <= y. Can I do better than a table scan? I've read similar questions in SO and Google but they seem to involve a single date within a range, which is different to my case.

No, this is not a XY question. This is exactly my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to use a Query instead of Scan.

Query needs `EQ` operator for hash key conditions, while in your case I see no `EQ` condition for any key.